# What are the conditions to finish a level?

Tags: droplitz

In Droplitz, I am stuck on level 4: I play for a bit less than ten minutes, and manage to get to the eighth table or so, but I end up with no droplet left and this is game over. I wonder whether I am missing some rules of the game, for instance: what are the conditions to finish a level? Maybe I am no trying to fulfill the correct conditions to finish the level?

---

Edit: It seems I have finally unlocked level 5 but I still don't understand what happened. Is there a score threshold to meet?